# Mix two materials in the Blender Internal Materials Nodes

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, node-editor

I studying the node in the Blender internal (not Cycles render). In an exercice, I want to mix two materials. I create a sphere, I apply the first material with a texture and it is going. In the second task, I create an other materials without texture and I need to mix the two materials using the Mix node. The problem is Mix does not exist in the shaders node and exist in the compositing nodes or texture nodes. In addition, I can't show at the same time the nodes corresponding to the two materials in the 
shaders node? How can I Mix the two materials. I am using this tutorial [tuto blender](https://sites.google.com/a/blendercycles.com/www/tips/introduction-to-material-nodes)

[image: Material with texture]
[image: Material without texture]

Answer (score 7):

since the material nodes output is Color type you can mix them using the RGB_Mix node :

[image]